# How to filter and redirect output

Tags: io-redirection

I have a command which will produce lots of output to STDOUT, which I know can be redirected into a file this way:

```
./myCMD 1>tmp
```

How can the output be filtered before redirecting it into the file. For example, I would want to redirect only those lines of output which contain some key word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean that you only want some lines to go to the `tmp` file, while the rest are left untouched:

```
cmd | awk '/pattern/ {print > "tmp"; next}
           {print}'
```

Or:

```
cmd | sed '/pattern/!b
           w tmp
           d'
```

(on one line: `cmd | sed -e '/pattern/!b' -e 'w tmp' -e d`)

Or:

```
cmd | sed '/pattern/ {
             w tmp
             d
           }'
```

(on one line: `cmd | sed -e '/pattern/{w tmp' -e 'd;}'`)

Note that for `sed`, `pattern` is a *basic* regular expression, while for `awk`, it's an *extended* regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with pipes:

```
./myCMD | grep keyword > tmp
```

This will only write lines containing “keyword” to the `tmp` file.

If you want to see the full output, but only log a subset to a file, add `tee` (assuming your shell supports process substitution):

```
./myCMD | tee >(grep keyword > tmp)
```

Comment: while i prefer grep, for some reason, didn't work for me on osx, but sed solution does